# Didn't find class "android.view.animation-list" in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to create simple [Android Drawable animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) of a rolling dice by having a series of images that constitute the animation. However, the program cannot start and is giving a runtime `fatal exception`:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class animation-list

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class animation-list

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.animation-list" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.demouser.scarnesdice-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.demouser.scarnesdice-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

(In which `demouser` is the name of the laptop user, and `scarnes dice` is the name of the program)

I'm not sure how to fix the **didn't find the class android animation list** ?

This is my xml code for this part:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll4" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll5" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll6" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll7" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll8" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll9" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll10" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll11" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roll12" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

This is my code in the main activity class:

```
package com.example.demouser.scarnesdice;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DiceRolling extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView diceView;
private AnimationDrawable rollAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dice_rolling);
    // Get and influence the dice view
    diceView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    diceView.setImageResource(R.drawable.roll1);
    rollAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) diceView.getBackground();
    handleRollButton();
}

public void handleRollButton() {
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rollAnimation.start();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Below is my module-level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.demouser.scarnesdice"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}

repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line in your error log

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class animation-list
```

Check your XML having this header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Line 0 should have the above header

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I add Multidex as in your instruction, then clean and rebuild the project. (I added my gradle file above). However it's still giving the exact same error. What do you think I should try now?

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem! Yes you're right - this is needed for every xml file. Another thing is: the animation-list must be put into a separate xml file, and then must be in put into res/drawable folder. I didn't do either of these things, which was why it complained. But it works well and the animation runs nicely now !